# Modal isn't covering the whole document

Tags: css, position, height, width

I am currently trying to make my .modal class's black background span the whole document length and width (not just the whole viewport, which it is currently doing). It would also be great to make it so you couldn't scroll the document anymore until you interacted with it.

I have verified that its parent container would be body, which I believe should be at least 600px due to my containers having a minimum height of 300px each and them being stacked on top of each other. I have used both 100% width and 100% height and absolutely positioned my element but have had no luck with it covering anything past the bottom of the viewport. I used z-index to ensure it was sitting on top of the other elements in the page and nothing seems to work.

`````````````````
<body>
  <main class="todo">
    <section class="todo__ctn todo__ctn--lists">
      <span>Hello man...lists</span>
    </section>
    <section class="todo__ctn todo__ctn--tasks">
      <span>Hello man...tasks</span>
    </section>
  </main>

  <div class="modal">
    <div class="modal__content">
      <p>Hello Man...content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
````````````````
/* SCSS Styling */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.todo {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit,minmax(300px,1fr));
  border: 1px solid black;
  &__ctn {
    min-height: 300px;
    &:first-child {
      border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }
  }
  &__ctn--lists {
    background: gold;
  }
  &__ctn--tasks {
    background: tan;
  }
}

.modal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
  color: orange;
  &__content {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: white;
  }
}

Like I had mentioned, I would like to have the black background persist, even when you scroll down the page. Once I scroll past the bottom of the viewport, the black background seems to stop and I don't know why.
`````````````````

Comment: Sorry, I'd like to understand your problem further. When I put your code into a fiddle and set the height of `.modal` to 200%, the black (slightly transparent) portion extends beyond the window. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Yes @Christopher Bennett, that is what I want the behavior to be but I want the positioning to automatically go there and stay there. For example, leaving the height at 200% is great, until I add a few more sections and then the content passes that 200% mark leaving the same problem. I hope that makes sense.